# Does the soap:address variable within a WSDL file contain the location of the web service?

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am integrating with a webservice who have provided a wsdl file to access the functionality. The web service will ultimately be run locally but I am currently testing it on their servers remotely. The WSDL file (which they claim should permit access to their remote servers) has the following within the services section:

```
      <soap:address location="http://localhost/webservices/15/login.asmx" />
```

Am I going mad or does this not mean that it's looking for the webservice on the local machine and not remotely (and presumably this should actually be pointing to the web server on their remote machine)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `soap:address` is only a hint as to where the service might be located.

Comment: So there is no specific definition of where it's located, this should be defined separately outside of the WDSL (i'm using PHP by the way)?

Comment: There could be multiple services with the same WSDL located at different URLs. It's not _defined_ anywhere.

Comment: So (in PHP) if the location variable is specified when connecting it uses that, otherwise it uses the address wthin the soap:address variable (or is this literally never used)? Otherwise the url of the web service should be specified within the location variable in addition to specifying the location of the WSDL file? eg new SoapClient("some.wsdl", array('location' => "http://remotedomain.com/soap.php"))? Thanks :)

Comment: I have no idea how PHP works. With .NET, one would set the URL at runtime if necessary, or place it into configuration.

Comment: So what is the point of having a WSDL if it does not define the correct URL of where you can find the service? I think the soap:address is not just a hint, but should point to the actual location of the service.

Comment: You are mistaken. The point of the WSDL is to define the _service_, not the location of the service. It defines the operations and bindings and the structure of the data and faults used in the operations. You might not realize this if you're used to a language like PHP which operates dynamically and needs to read the WSDL at runtime.