# How to connect to a remote web service via php using a local WSDL file?

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

If I want to connect to a third party web service via PHP using a local WSDL file am I right in thinking I should do the following:

```
$client = new SoapClient("thefile.wsdl", array('location' => "http://anotherdomain.com/soap.asmx"));
```

If you are using a WSDL file then presumably you can exclude the uri (namespace) variable? And if you don't specify the location here then does it just use the soap:address defined within the services section of the WSDL file?

Thanks!

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location is (/should be) in the wsdl, so a `location` in the 2nd argument is not necessary. OTOH, I don't know what happens if you specify *another* location, you could simply test this, I would guess it ignores it (as locations can also be specified per action, the wsdl should trump it IMO).

Comment: That is what I thought but got confused based on a response to one of my other questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9085571/does-the-soapaddress-variable-within-a-wsdl-file-contain-the-location-of-the-we/9085590#9085590. Should the web services url be defined in the soap:address element within the services section of the WSDL then? Thanks very much

Comment: In any decent wsdl I have seen the `address` is no hint, but ports and endpoints actually define their definitive address. I must admit I do not know 100% sure whether is it required ([the documentation](http://xml.coverpages.org/wsdl20000929.html#_ports) does not say 'must contain one', just 'not more then one'. However, I would assume that they were, and if they are not, they are not probably not discoverable, and I'd add them in the 3rd argument of [`__soapCall`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php)

Comment: Hm, [that documentation states](http://xml.coverpages.org/wsdl20000929.html#_soap:address): _"The SOAP address binding is used to give a port an address (a URI). A port using the SOAP binding MUST specify exactly one address."_.

Comment: In short: that Port should IMHO be defined properly (as the whole point of SOAP is it is _discoverable_), but I cannot state 100% this is required by the format and/or whether people break that convention on a massive scale. Anecdotal evidence in _my_ consumption of SOAP services is that it is always well defined.

Comment: So you should just use $client = new SoapClient("thefile.wsdl"); which will use the <soap:address location> variable within the wsdl file as the webservice location?

Comment: Yep, unless you cannot work with that (non-local service in development etc.), in which case, use the 3rd argument in `__soapCall`.

Comment: Thanks so much for confirming that. I am using it to test a webservice that will ultimately be local but is currently running remotely on their servers. They supplied a WSDL file with a local uri in the soap:address field, I was originally trying to confirm that what they'd provided was wrong and this should contain a remote uri? Thanks so much for your help and sorry for asking questions in the comments!

Answer (score 0):

It would be simply

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://anotherdomain.com/soap.asmx", array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_1));
```